# Can I get individual data by paillier decryption if we send aggregated encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, paillier

Suppose there are different users data for $n$ Smart meters. We encrypt all the individual data and then add them together. After decrypting the summation, how can we retrieve the original data? We are using pallier cryptography.

Comment: How would you expected it to work if Pallier wasn't involved?  Suppose you take all the individual data, don't encrypt them and add them together.  With the summation, would you expect to be able to retrieve the original data?

Answer (score 0):

Applying literally

> encrypt all the individual data and then add them together

would yield a useless mess. One wants to *multiply modulo $n^2$* the encrypted values $V_i$, where $n$ is the public modulus in the Pailler public key, yielding $V=\prod V_i\bmod n^2$. Then when $V$ is decrypted using the private key yielding $v$, that's the sum of the meter values (modulo $n$, but since $n$ is so large, that does not matter): $v=\sum v_i\bmod n$.

With proper implementation of Paillier encryption, for one not knowing the private key, the $V_i$ leak no information about the individual $v_i$.

From $V$ it can't be found the individual $v_i$, even for the holder of the private key. Of course, knowing $v=\sum v_i$ and perhaps some $v_i$ yields some information about the other $v_i$.

From the individual encrypted meter values $V_i$, the holder of the private key can get at the individual meter values $v_i$. Depending on the operating procedures of the holder of the private key, it might be possible for others to obtain some $v_i$.

---

Note: Altering a single bit in any of the $V_i$ will make $v$ totally wrong. And anyone can prepare a $V_i$ coding any value $v_i$ they see fit, including slightly negative. Therefore, integrity of the $V_i$ would be critical in a real system. BTW, I wish I knew any industrial use of homomorphic encryption.